# Does SwiftUI support alternate layouts by preferred font size?

Tags: fonts, accessibility, swiftui, dynamic-type-feature

Ideally, an iOS app uses font sizes that follow the user's system-wide font size setting. The topic is covered in a WWDC talk from 2017 called *Building Apps with Dynamic Type*.

In simple cases, you set a `UIView`'s font using named styles like `body`, `caption1`, `title`, which vary in size depending on the user's settings.

In trickier cases, you need to write different auto-layout constraints for different font sizes. For example, horizontally stacked labels may need to become vertically stacked when the font is larger.

[image]

[image]

For this situation, the WWDC talk shows some code like this:

```
if traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory > .extraExtraLarge {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate( horizontalConstraints )
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate( verticalConstraints )
} else {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate( verticalConstraints )
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate( horizontalConstraints )
}
```

What is the equivalent to this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest I can think of would be something like that:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory: ContentSizeCategory

    let largeSizeCategories: [ContentSizeCategory] = [.extraExtraLarge,
                                                      .extraExtraExtraLarge,
                                                      .accessibilityMedium,
                                                      .accessibilityLarge,
                                                      .accessibilityExtraLarge,
                                                      .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge,
                                                      .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge]

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if largeSizeCategories.contains(sizeCategory) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Pizza, bananas, donuts")
                    Text("Io, Europa, Ganymede")
                }
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Text("Pizza, bananas, donuts")
                    Text("Io, Europa, Ganymede")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Get the `ContentSizeCategory` from the `Environment` and adjust your view depending on the value.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like `ContentSizeCategory` should have comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, etc.) and `isAccessibilityCategory`, like `UIContentSizeCategory`. I filed feedback to request them.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 16 you can now use an [`AnyLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anylayout) instance to dynamically transition between layouts (conforming to the `Layout` protocol) while still maintaining your subview's identity.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.dynamicTypeSize) private var dynamicTypeSize

    var body: some View {
        let layout = dynamicTypeSize > .xxLarge ? AnyLayout(VStackLayout()) : AnyLayout(HStackLayout())

        layout {
            Text("Pizza, bananas, donuts")
            Text("Io, Europa, Ganymede")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `ContentSizeCategory` has been [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/sizecategory) in iOS 17. The example above uses `DynamicTypeSize` instead.